# GlideAjax not executing from client script

Tags: javascript, ajax, client, backend, servicenow

I'm having a really, really hard time understanding why my Ajax call won't run. Made a small example:

```
// Client script
function onSubmit() {
    var ga = new GlideAjax('global.CheckUser');
    ga.addParam('sysparm_name', 'Validate');
    ga.getXMLAnswer(exec);
    
    function exec (response){
        console.log('resp: ' + response); // Response is null...
    }
}

// Script include
var CheckUser = Class.create();
CheckUser.prototype = Object.extendsObject(AbstractAjaxProcessor, {
    Validate: function() {
        gs.log('Hello world ...', 'Test'); // This doesn't get logged in sys log. 
        return true;
    },

    type: 'CheckUser'
});
```

From what I can tell the Validate function isn't even called, as "Hello world ..." isn't found in system log afterwards. Response is null in console.log, even though it should be true.

Script include is **client callable** with an execute ACL requireing role "itil" - which the user has.
Client script has **isolate script** set to false.

I simple for the life of me cannot understand why this isn't working... helllp :D

Comment: Is it possible that you have two Script Includes named "CheckUser"?